# Cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt32]'

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, arc4random

I have an array of numbers that have been generated randomly and I am then trying to query Firebase for a question that is equal to the value at index [0] in the array of chosen numbers. The problem at the moment is that I get an error `Cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt32]'`. P.S. I am not extremly experienced in swift so exact code solutions would be very apreciated! I have also attached my firebase structure...

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class QuestionViewController: UIViewController {


let ref = Firebase(url: "https://123test123.firebaseio.com/questions")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // An empty array to hold the selected numbers
    var selectedNumbers: [UInt32] = []

    // A range of acceptable numbers
    let randomNumberRange = 1...10

    // How many numbers are needed?
    let randomNumbersToChoose = 10

    // Crash if asking for more numbers than are available in the range
    assert(randomNumberRange.count >= randomNumbersToChoose, "Must have enough numbers to choose from!")

    // Repeat this loop until all enough numbers have been selected
    while selectedNumbers.count < randomNumbersToChoose {

        // Pick a random number within the allowed range
        let selectedNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomNumberRange.endIndex - randomNumberRange.startIndex)) + UInt32(randomNumberRange.startIndex)

        // If it's not already in the selected array, add it
        if (selectedNumbers.indexOf(selectedNumber) == nil) {
            selectedNumbers.append(selectedNumber)
        }
    }

    // Print the result
    print(selectedNumbers)


        print(selectedNumbers)
        let selectedNumberIndex: UInt32 = 2
        ref.queryOrderedByChild("value").queryEqualToValue(selectedNumbers[0])
            .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
                snapshot in
                //Do something with the question
                print(snapshot.key)
                print(snapshot.value.valueForKey("question"))
            })
    }

@IBAction func truepressed(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func falsePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
}

}
```

JSON data:

```
{
  "question1" : {
    "answer" : "Nohghpe",
    "question" : "Do you know swift",
    "value" : 1
  },
  "question10" : {
    "answer" : "A fdsbit",
    "question" : "Do you kndfggow firebase",
    "value" : 10
  },
  "question2" : {
    "answer" : "A bfhit",
    "question" : "Dodhfg you know firebase",
    "value" : 2
  },
  "question3" : {
    "answer" : "A bsdit",
    "question" : "Do you know firebsgdfase",
    "value" : 3
  },
  "question4" : {
    "answer" : "A vcxbit",
    "question" : "Do yosgfdu know firebase",
    "value" : 4
  },
  "question5" : {
    "answer" : "A bivcxt",
    "question" : "Do you kfghnow firebase",
    "value" : 5
  },
  "question6" : {
    "answer" : "A bxcvit",
    "question" : "Do you know fnhirebase",
    "value" : 6
  },
  "question7" : {
    "answer" : "A bivxct",
    "question" : "Do you sgdfknow firebase",
    "value" : 7
  },
  "question8" : {
    "answer" : "A bivcxt",
    "question" : "Do you knsfdow firebase",
    "value" : 8
  },
  "question9" : {
    "answer" : "A bdsfit",
    "question" : "Do you kdfgnow ffsdirebase",
    "value" : 9
  }
}
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done. I know is looks a bit odd but this is the only way I managed to do it. Bare in mind the questions are just dummy questions :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the edits. Cleaning up the comments...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a typical situation of the Swift compiler obscuring the real error behind another one. The [`.queryEqualToValue(..)` method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FQuery.html) expects an argument of type `AnyObject`; which can hold only reference (class) types, whereas `UInt32` is a value type.

Another subject of confusion could be that we're generally used to the fact that `AnyObject` types can, *seemingly*, hold `Int` types, when in fact such assignments implicitly converts the Swift native `Int` value type to the Foundation `__NSCFNumber` reference type. This implicit conversion is, however, not available for `UInt32` type.

```
var a : AnyObject?
let foo : [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
let bar : [UInt32] = [1, 2, 3]

/* OK: Int -> [implicitly] -> __NSCFNumber */
a = foo[0]
print(a!.dynamicType) // __NSCFNumber

/* Not OK */
a = bar[0]
/* error: cannot subscript a value of type '[UInt32]' a = bar[0] */
```

Hence, you could solve this issue by:

1. Letting `selectedNumbers` be an array 0f `Int`, rather than `UInt32` (and modify the affected parts of your code accordingly).
2. Perform a type conversion from `UInt32` to `Int` in your call to `.queryEqualToValue(..)`. E.g., in the example above:

   ```
   a = Int(bar[0])
   ```

   Just take care that for 32-bit systems (e.g. iPhone 5), half the upper range of numbers representable by `UInt32` type cannot be represented by `Int` type, since on 32-bit system, `Int` corresponds to `Int32`.

   ```
   INT32_MAX   // 2147483647
   UINT32_MAX  // 4294967295
   ```

   From a quick glance at your code, however, it doesn't seem as if this should be an issue here, as the elements of `selectedNumbers` will not contain the larger numbers representable by `UInt32` (and, for 64-bit systems: OK, as `Int` corresponds to `Int64`). If choosing this option, you should, however, for good practice, assert prior to conversion that the `UInt32` value can be represented by the `Int` type on the systems intended to run your application.

Comment: @TomFox Happy to help.